# D3.js rotate shape without rotating text inside

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation

I want to create rotate animation in a d3.js chart. With help of Gilsha I was able to create a chart like this :[image]

Now on click of any of the outer circles i want to rotate all circles and align the one which was clicked in the place of "hllooo" circle.

I have copied one angletween which is rotating the circles but the problem is that text inside that circle also gets rotated and creates something like this:

[image]

As you can see the text is also rotated which i dont want. The code for `transform` function is:

```
function angleTween(d, i) {
            var angle = 360 - ((i + 1) * 70);
            var i = d3.interpolate(0, 90);
            return function (t) {
                return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
            };
        }
```

So how to keep text unrotated and just rotate the shape ?

Comment: Akshat, I think it would be better to put the text outside the group and update its positions by just updating the x and y positions within the `angleTween` method. So that the rotation will not get applied on texts. Have a try, if still not able to get, add a fiddle so that I can look into it.

Comment: But then how to calculate new x and y for text ?

Comment: Should i create two groups inside one main group to make things easier ?

Comment: Akshat, I am trying to make a demo of the same. will let you know once complete. Is your angletween function working fine?

Comment: yes gilsha. Its working fine. i am also trying to achieve what u said.

Comment: I am trying to modify getcirclepoints function for text points after a 90 degree rotate applied. I have changed new function like this:

Comment: `function getTextPoints(points, radius, center) {
            var circlePositions = [];
            var slice = 2 * Math.PI / points;

            for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
                var angle = slice * i;
                var newX = (center.X + radius * Math.cos(angle + 80));
                var newY = (center.Y + radius * Math.sin(angle + 80));
                circlePositions.push({
                    cx: newX,
                    cy: newY
                });
            }
            return circlePositions;
        }`

Comment: by mistake i have written 80 but its 90. Its not working as expected. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calulcate the x and y attributes of text elements by using `SVGPoint  matrixTransform`.

```
earth.on('click', function() {
    texts.style("opacity", 0);
    earthLayer
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("transform", angleTween)
        .each("end", function() {
            var svgEl = this.ownerSVGElement;
            var angle = d3.select(this).attr("transform").match(/\d+/g)[0];
            var matrix = svgEl.createSVGMatrix().rotate(angle);
            texts.each(function(d, i) {
                var point = this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
                point.x = +d.cx;
                point.y = +d.cy;
                point = point.matrixTransform(matrix);
                d3.select(this).attr("x", point.x).attr("y", point.y);
            });
            texts.style("opacity", 1);
        });
});
```

```js
var now = d3.time.year.floor(new Date());

var spacetime = d3.select('body');
var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height);

var radii = {
    "sun": radius / 6,
    "earthOrbit": radius / 2.5,
    "earth": radius / 15,
    "moonOrbit": radius / 16,
    "moon": radius / 96
};

// Space
var svg = spacetime.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Sun
var sun = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "sun")
    .attr("r", radii.sun)
    //.style("fill", "rgba(255, 204, 0, 1.0)");
    .style("stroke", "#f58c2e")
    .style("stroke-width", "10")
    .style("fill", "none");

// Earth's orbit
var orbit = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "earthOrbit")
    .attr("r", radii.earthOrbit)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "#bababa")
    .style("stroke-width", "30");

// Current position of Earth in its orbit
var earthOrbitPosition = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radii.earthOrbit + 1)
    .innerRadius(radii.earthOrbit - 1)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "earthOrbitPosition")
    .attr("d", earthOrbitPosition)
    .style("fill", "rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.75)");


// Time of day
var day = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radii.earth)
    .innerRadius(0)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("d", day)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -radii.earthOrbit + ")")
    .style("fill", "rgba(53, 110, 195, 1.0)");


// Current position of the Moon in its orbit
var moonOrbitPosition = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radii.moonOrbit + 1)
    .innerRadius(radii.moonOrbit - 1)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "moonOrbitPosition")
    .attr("d", moonOrbitPosition)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -radii.earthOrbit + ")")
    .style("fill", "rgba(113, 170, 255, 0.75)");

function getCirclePoints(points, radius, center) {
    var circlePositions = [];
    var slice = 2 * Math.PI / points;
    for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        var angle = slice * i;
        var newX = (center.X + radius * Math.cos(angle));
        var newY = (center.Y + radius * Math.sin(angle));
        circlePositions.push({
            cx: newX,
            cy: newY
        });
    }
    return circlePositions;
}

var circlePositions = getCirclePoints(10, radii.earthOrbit, {
    X: 0,
    Y: 0
});
var earthLayer = svg.append("g").classed("earthLayer", true);
var textLayer = svg.append("g").classed("textLayer", true);
var earth = earthLayer.selectAll(".earth").data(circlePositions)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.cx;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.cy;
    })
    .attr("class", "earth")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", radii.earth)
    .style("stroke", "#bababa")
    .style("stroke-width", "10");

texts = textLayer.selectAll("text").data(circlePositions).enter().append("text").attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.cx
}).attr("dx", -radii.earth / 2).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.cy
}).text(function(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) return "hllooo";
    else return "hllooo" + i;
});

earth.on('click', function() {
    texts.style("opacity", 0);
    earthLayer
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("transform", angleTween)
        .each("end", function() {
            var svgEl = this.ownerSVGElement;
            var angle = d3.select(this).attr("transform").match(/\d+/g)[0];
            var matrix = svgEl.createSVGMatrix().rotate(angle);
            texts.each(function(d, i) {
                var point = this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
                point.x = +d.cx;
                point.y = +d.cy;
                point = point.matrixTransform(matrix);
                d3.select(this).attr("x", point.x).attr("y", point.y);
            });
            texts.style("opacity", 1);
        });
});

function angleTween(d, i) {
    var angle = 360 - ((i + 1) * 70);
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, angle);
    return function(t) {
        return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried that gilsha.But whats the probem is the text goes back to original place shown in the image 1.

Comment: I want to find the angle between the clicked element and the one which is in the center of right side (which is hlooo in first image). Is this the correct solution ? 
[link]http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185829/how-do-you-find-an-angle-between-two-points-on-the-edge-of-a-circle
And what if i want to rotate the element from its last rotated position ?Like first 90 degrees and then again 90 from the last 90 degree rotated  position. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use this equation. `var angle = Math.atan((p1y - p2y) / (p2x - p1x)) * (180 / Math.PI);`